# How can I use pageobject navigation routes when I have multiple methods with parameters?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

Here, I have two methods in a class with one parameter each and I want to use routes advantage. How can I pass parameters if I am using cucumber I mean how can I pass parameters from step definitions to method if I use like this:

### feature:

```
Feature: Github Test Case

Background:
  Given I am on githubpage

Scenario Outline: I should see one of the repositories
  When I click on "<user>" and select "<repo>" link
  Then I should see "Information Technology Association website repo"

Examples:
  | user   | repo        |
  | sample | sample_repo |
```

### step def:

```
Given(/^I am on githubpage$/) do
 visit(LoginPage).do_login
end

Then(/^I should see "([^"]*)"$/) do |message|
  @current_page.text.should include message
end


When(/^I click on "([^"]*)" and select "([^"]*)" link$/) do |user, repo|
 # currently using like this
 navigate_to(GithubPage).click_on(user)
 navigate_to(GithubPage).select_repo(repo)

 # but i need like this
 navigate_to(GithubPage).select_repo

 # or
 navigate_all
end
```

### class:

```
  class GithubPage
  include PageObject

  link(:repo, text: /Repositories/)

  def click_on(user)
    span_element(text: "#{user}", index: 1).click
    repo_element.click
  end

  def select_repo(repo)
    link_element(xpath: "//a[contains(text(),'#{repo}')]").when_present.click
  end
end
```

### routes:

```
PageObject::PageFactory.routes = {
    :default => [[GithubPage, :click_on], [GithubPage, :select_repo]]
}
```

Comment: Or can any body suggest me a better approach to use when using Scenario Outline with routing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example from [PageObject::PageFactory](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/page-object/1.0.2/symbols/PageObject::PageFactory) where Cheezy passes an argument to a method as part of his routes definition:

```
PageObject::PageFactory.routes = {
  :default => [[PageOne,:method1], [PageTwoA,:method2], [PageThree,:method3]],
  :another_route => [[PageOne,:method1, "arg1"], [PageTwoB,:method2b], [PageThree,:method3]]
}
```

The problem is, of course, that you don't have that argument at the time these routes are defined. You need to load them dynamically. Something like this *might* work, but I haven't tested it:

```
When /^I click on "([^"]*)" and select "([^"]*)" link$/ do |user, repo|
  PageObject::PageFactory.routes[:default].map do |route|
    route << user if route[1] == :click_on
    route << repo if route[1] == :select_repo 
  end
  navigate_all
end
```

But if you're going to go to all that trouble, you're better off passing a block to PageObject::PageFactory#on:

```
When /^I click on "([^"]*)" and select "([^"]*)" link$/ do |user, repo|
  on GithubPage do |page|
    page.click_on user
    page.select_repo repo
  end
end
```